# How to download Remote file in Laravel to server?

Tags: php, laravel

I have one CSV file which is uploaded to S3 using Laravel Storage facade. Now this file needs to be download to my server for further processing on it. How this can be done in Laravel or PHP ?

Comment: use file_get_contents,curl, guzzile,etc plenty of choices

Comment: `$contents = Storage::disk('s3')->get('data.csv');`